# passportJS - passport-facebook cannot GET failureRedirect route

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, facebook-login

Following the [passportJS docs](http://passportjs.org/docs/facebook) for passport-facebook I am trying to implement express middleware for facebook authentication. I am using [mongoose-findorcreate](https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-findorcreate) to create the findOrCreate function needed for passportJS.

I am able to redirect to the facebook login form, and login with my facebook credentials. But afterwards I get redirected to the failureRedirect URL which return the following:

> Cannot GET
>   /auth/facebook/callback?code=AQBsq2xY-YTsNMmipM45BVBBC9W1QovO1grjC64nDe1psWuRZQwjGv8SMpXuou3s9SaVIIS0_3RqJn-SQ339wPD_TWjRPIpXpZZVHerTRZEQnQYLvt1CM0qMzG5R_JNqfYib6rkmuP4epXou5HoqUa01qszUpYfGMPHUYyNVx1VdMSu3RLbdta8rYle9am539NzYL8ihlwlflnFku-8H3QqlzWJ5Ta1pQ29N0ZyRRu38nKzrDQk-jE5Sq9WECDZ6aUX-KWvexM_5UAUJ60crUPFVxZyWwV__5N6DyDEpS9SrWKdcrpdwcMOd4u0z6mbK7os

This is my model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');

// Schema definition
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  provider: String,
  id: String,
  displayName: String,
  name: [
    {familyName: String},
    {givenName: String},
    {middleName: String},
  ],
  emails: [
    {value: String},
    {type: String},
  ],
  photos: [
    {value: String},
  ],
});

userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

// Compile model from schema
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

The passport part of the app:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: conf.facebookClientID,
    clientSecret: conf.facebookSecret,
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback',
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate(function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

// Authentication routes
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    successRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000/words',
    failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook',
  }));
```

I am trying to figure out why the login fails, and why the user does not get written into my database (I can query the database for other stuff so I know the connection is valid).

If you need more information about the project please ask and I will edit the question. You can also check the [gitHub repo](https://github.com/Shooshte/veryNiceWords-API/tree/passport-facebook).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alter:

```
app.get('auth/facebook/callback'
```

to:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback'
```

Comment: ugh, that simple. Thanks